# How does createBottomTabNavigator modify the title?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

## mycode

routers.js

```js
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import home from '../views/home';
import my from '../views/my';

const RouteConfigs = {
  home: {
    screen: home, // This attribute works
    tabBarLabel: 'cc', // Why he didn't work
    showLabel: false, // Why he didn't work
  },
  my: {
    screen: my,
  },
};

const TabOptions = {
  swipeEnabled: true,
  animationEnabled: true,
};

const StackNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(RouteConfigs, TabOptions);

export default StackNavigator;
```

```js
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

import routers from './routers';

export default createAppContainer(routers);
```

### problem

expected：  ['cc', 'my']

But the actual result：  ['home', 'my']

```
screen: home, // This attribute works
tabBarLabel: 'cc', // Why he didn't work
showLabel: false, // Why he didn't work
```

doc: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass them as `navigationOptions` :

```
  home: {
    screen: home, 
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "cc"
    }
  }
```

About the label part, you can only change it globally on the bottomTabNavigator:

```
const TabOptions = {
   swipeEnabled: true,
   animationEnabled: true,
   tabBarOptions: {
      showLabel : false
   }
};
```

If you want to hide it in a specific tab you can pass:

```
navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: " "
}
```